# Efficient way to run PowerShell Pester tests from Sublime Text

Tags: powershell, sublimetext, sublimetext3, powershell-3.0, pester

I'm using Sublime Text (ST) to create my PowerShell scripts, Pester to test them.

To run test script, one must to switch to that tab, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.  This process must be repeated for each test script.

Is there an easy way to Sublime Text to run all of the tests in the project's directory?

Is there a way to have these test automatically run when a script or test changes (similar to [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a script named `Tests.ps1` to the project's directory with a single instruction:

```
Invoke-Pester
```

To run all tests, I open this file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

** edit **

Created a new build system named 'Pester'.  The contents of `Pester.sublimebuild`:

```
{
    "cmd": ["powershell.exe", "-noprofile", "Invoke-Pester"],
    "selector": "source.powershell"
}
```

To run all tests, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

If this doesn't work automatically, assign Pester as the build system using `Tools | Build System | Pester` and try again.